# How Do I Fix this Return/Global Error?

Tags: python, global

```
def subtract(num):
    string = str(num)
    a = string[0]
    b = string[1]
    c = string[2]
    large = max(a, b, c)
    small = min(a,b,c)
    summation = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
    mid = summation - int(large) - int(small)
    mid2 = str(mid)
    ascend = large + mid2 + small
    descend = small + mid2 + large
    print('The digits in ascending order are', ascend)
    print('The digits in descending order are', descend)
    value = int(descend) - int(ascend)
    return value
def main():
    dummy = input('Type a three digit integer, please.\n')
    if not len(dummy) == 3:
        print('Error!')
        main()
    elif not dummy.isdigit():
        print('Error!')
        main()
    if len(dummy) == 3 and dummy.isdigit():
        subtract(dummy)
        print('The value of the digits in descending order minus the digits in ascending order is', value)
main()
```

When I input a a number like 123, I get:

```
Type a three digit integer, please.
123
The digits in ascending order are 321
The digits in descending order are 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/philvollman/Documents/NYU/Freshman /Fall Semester/Intro to Computer Programming/Assignments/Homework5PartA.py", line 29, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/philvollman/Documents/NYU/Freshman /Fall Semester/Intro to Computer Programming/Assignments/Homework5PartA.py", line 28, in main
print('The value of the digits in descending order minus the digits in ascending order is', value2)
NameError: global name 'value2' is not defined
>>>
```

I am not sure why I am getting this because my first function only runs if the if statements are true and the returned value should be returned within the if statement.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't have a `value2` in it at all, so I'm going to say it isn't identical to the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 4):

In the call to `print` at the end of `main` you refer to a variable named `value` that has not been defined in `main`. Hence the error. Perhaps you meant to retain the value returned from  the call to `subtract`:

```
value = subtract(dummy)
print('The value ... is', value)
```

I must admit to finding your code a little difficult to follow, not least because the error message you posted does not quite match the code you posted.

---

I think your basic misunderstanding concerns how functions return values. When you call a function that returns a value, you must assign that value to something in the calling scope's namespace.

So when you wrote

```
subtract(dummy)
```

a value was returned but because you did not assign it to anything, that value was forgotten.

Instead you have to assign it to something in order to use it

```
value = subtract(dummy)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `return value` at the end of your function `subtract` makes that value *available* to the caller, it doesn't magically inject it into the caller's namespace.

Try

```
value2 = subtract(dummy)
```

and go from there ...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because you are referring to a variable by name (value) that is not defined in the scope of main (btw. your posted code does not match the error message - there is no value2 there ;).

So either do

```
print('The value of the digits in descending order minus the digits in ascending order is', subtract(dummy))
```

or

```
value = subtract(dummy)
print('The value of the digits in descending order minus the digits in ascending order is', value)
```

Returning a value from a function just returns the plain value, not the name of any variable defined within that function.